# CSS code to put specific list element in italic (without changing html code)

Tags: html, css

Given the following html code what is the CSS code to put the third element in the list (that is the word "beautiful") in italic ? Of course, I could give an id or a class to this element but the html code must stay unchanged. Thanks

```
<div id = "presentation">
    <h2>presentation</h2>
    <p>She is :</p>
    <ul>
        <li>nice</li>
        <li>lovely</li>
        <li>beautiful</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ul li:nth-child(3)`

```css
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id = "presentation">
    <h2>presentation</h2>
    <p>She is :</p>
    <ul>
        <li>nice</li>
        <li>lovely</li>
        <li>beautiful</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```